# Why doesn't navigation link/view appear on the toolbar?

Tags: ios, swift

This is my code

```
 var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("People")) {
                ForEach(people) { person in
                    PersonListItem(data: .constant(person))
                }
            }
        }.listStyle(InsetListStyle())
            .toolbar {
                NavigationLink(destination: NewPerson(personData: .constant(Person.empty))){
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
            }
    }
```

On running it shows The section "People" and it's contents. But doesn't show the plus sign on the toolbar. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapped your form with `NavigationView`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{ // Here
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("People")) {
                    ForEach(people) { person in
                        PersonListItem(data: .constant(person))
                    }
                }
            }.listStyle(InsetListStyle())
                .toolbar {
                    NavigationLink(destination: NewPerson(personData: .constant(Person.empty))){
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    }
                }.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}
```